# The indentfirst package does not work with ragged2e package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, ragged2e

I am using the `ragged2e` package in the `article` class and want the first paragraph within the `justify` environment to be indented. As such, I used the `indentfirst` package. However, this does not change the indentation of the first paragraph. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Used to get good looking fully-justified (even on both sides) text
\usepackage{indentfirst} %Used to indent the first paragraph in a section

\usepackage{lipsum} %used to generate filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{justify}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{justify}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not that `indentfirst` doesn't work (my packages always work:-) it's just not relevant here as it only interacts with section headings. `justify` is a list internally so you need the itemindent to be the same as the parindent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Used to get good looking fully-justified (even on both sides) text
%\usepackage{indentfirst} %Used to indent the first paragraph in a section

\usepackage{lipsum} %used to generate filler text

\renewenvironment{justify}{%
   \trivlist
   \justifying
   \itemindent\JustifyingParindent
   \item\relax
   }{%
   \endtrivlist
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{justify}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{justify}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My apologies for the inappropriate title :) I've always thought of `\trivlist` as creating separate paragraphs, but it seems that metaphor breaks down here. Thanks for the help, David.

Comment: @adamglesser argualbly its a deficiency in the package that justify ought to give you a paragraph indent  as in the answer here unless the first para pf a section ie use something like  `\if@nobreak\if@afterindent\itemindent\JustifyingParindent\fi\else\itemindent\JustifyingParindent\fi`